# Parameters in PHP email script

Tags: php, email

I have written a php email script, Message from our Site suppose `My~PHP~Script.com` is sent to user eg: `abc@yahoo~mail.com` from eg: `def@yahoo~mail.com` in a particular format:

---

`Subject: def@yahoo~mail.com sent you a message Via My~PHP~Script~`

`From: noreply@My~PHP~Script.com`

`Message: Here is the message....`

---

Now I want that in Yahoo Mail (or in any other mail) if the person (`abc@yahoo~mail.com`) clicks on `Reply to mail` then Yahoo or (other mail sites) should pick up the email from subject (i.e. `def@yahoo~mail.com`) for replying.

Do I need to send any specific parameters to inform mail sites that at which address user can reply.... How to achieve the desired results...?

Comment: This technique I saw on WeTransfer.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `Reply-To` header available. Just set it to your email and it will be used when the user hits `Reply`

```
$recipient = '...';
$subject   = '...';
$message   = '...';

$headers   = "Reply-To: YOUR EMAIL HERE";

mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);
```